# Smart way to Copy/Dump Server database tables data in Android and iOS Application using Web service written in PHP

Tags: php, android, ios, performance, web-services

There are more than 30 tables present on my server database.So,need to get all the data present in tables should be retrieve using one web service for Android,iOS application.

Consider following points:

- I have some statistical informative utf-8 data store in different tables on server database.
- So I need to club all tables data into json/other formats.
- And I can get that json/other format using web service on application side.

For example (if we consider JSON), we consider three tables:

- Table A (id,name,address)
- Table B (key,value)
- Table C (title,price)

In this case the web service should return me the below response:

```
[
    {
        "A": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "ABC",
                "address": "XYZ"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "ABC",
                "address": "XYZ"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "B": [
            {
                "key": "test",
                "value": "XYZ"
            },
            {
                "key": "test1",
                "value": "LMN"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "C": [
            {
                "title": "PQR",
                "price": 20.5
            },
            {
                "title": "XYZ",
                "price": 20
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

So,

1. How I can write the Web Service in PHP which return me json show in above example?

   (Note: I already tried this with hitting separate query on each required table, but it takes 2-3 minutes to return data).
2. Web Service should returns data in max 5-7 seconds.

Comment: You should check just how much of that 2-3 minutes was spent on network transfer time v.s. the server generating the data. If almost all of that time is network, then there is NOTHING you can do to speed things up. No matter how much you speed up the server data collection, you can't change the transfer speed.

Comment: @MarcB I tested above scenario on 5 MBPS network its taking arround 2-3 minutes and on 2G network it takes arround 9-10 minutes.So I think it impacts as bad user experience about app

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this ?

```
    //queries
    $sql1 = "SELECT * from A";
    $sql2 = "SELECT * from B";
    $sql3 = "SELECT * from C";

    //prepare
    $stmt1 = $dbh->prepare( $sql1 );
    $stmt2 = $dbh->prepare( $sql2 );
    $stmt3 = $dbh->prepare( $sql3 );

    //execute
    $stmt1->execute();
    $stmt2->execute();
    $stmt3->execute();

    //get results
    $result1 = $stmt1->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
    $result2 = $stmt2->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
    $result3 = $stmt3->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );

    //convert to json
    $json1 = json_encode($result1, true);
    $json2 = json_encode($result2, true);
    $json3 = json_encode($result3, true);

    //merge jsons
    $json = json_encode(array_merge($json1, $json2, $json3));

    //echo result
    echo $json;
```

Comment: Yes,I did something like above